# yup schema .compact() method manipulates form data submitted

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I've got a form using [react-hook-form](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form) that validates submission by checking against a schema defined in [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup).

It works well, but if I apply `.compact()` to remove `false` values in order to count how many `true` values in the array with `.min(1)`, the data that comes out the other end of the `handleSubmit(onSubmit)` function has been manipulated by the schema validation process, and `false` values no longer reach the `onSubmit` function.

```js
const schema = yup
  .object({
    roles: yup
      .array()
      .compact()
      .min(1, "A user must have at least one role assigned"),
  })
  .required();

const MyForm = () => {
  const { handleSubmit } = useForm({resolver: yupResolver(schema)});

  const roles = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

  const onSubmit = ({roles}) => {
    console.log(roles); // [true, true]
    const selectedRoles = roles.filter((_r, i) => roleData[i]);
    console.log(selectedRoles); // ["foo", "bar"]; <— incorrect roles due to loss of false values
  }

  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    // ...form
    // example submission data from my form: `{ roles: [true, false, true] }`
    // ✅ foo
    // ❌ bar
    // ✅ baz
  </form>
};
```

1. Is there a way to stop `yup` from manipulating the output of the form, and only being used for schema validation?
2. If not, is there a way to return the full values after `.compact()` has removed some?
3. Is there a different way to validate that an array has at least `x` true values that won't manipulate the output of the form submission data?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to stop `yup` from manipulating the output of the data submitted at the end, but I've found a way to do the equivalent of `.compact().min(1)` using the `.test(name: string, message: string | function | any, test: function)` method:

```js
const schema = yup
  .object({
    roles: yup
      .array()
      .test(
        "min-1-true",
        "A user must have at least one role assigned",
        value => {
          const trueValues = value?.filter(v => v === true).length;
          return trueValues >= 1;
        },
      ),
  })
  .required();
```